# Reproduce setcap behavior with capsh

Tags: capabilities, setcap

There is a non-capability-aware program that requires at least 1) `cap_sys_admin` and 2) either `cap_dac_override` or `cap_dac_read_search`. This can be proven as follows:

```
sudo setcap 'all=ep cap_sys_admin-ep' ./binary`                        # ./binary doesn't work
sudo setcap 'all=ep cap_dac_override-ep' ./binary`                     # ./binary works
sudo setcap 'all=ep cap_dac_read_search-ep' ./binary                   # ./binary works
sudo setcap 'all=ep cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search-ep' ./binary  # ./binary doesn't work
```

I want to do the same checks using `capsh` instead of `setcap`.
Before these checks, all file capabilities are removed using `sudo setcap -r ./binary`.
The first tree succeed, the results match `setcap`:

```
sudo capsh --user=jdoe --keep=1 --caps="all=eip" --addamb="all" --delamb="cap_sys_admin" -- -c ./binary
sudo capsh --user=jdoe --keep=1 --caps="all=eip" --addamb="all" --delamb="cap_dac_override" -- -c ./binary
sudo capsh --user=jdoe --keep=1 --caps="all=eip" --addamb="all" --delamb="cap_dac_read_search" -- -c ./binary
```

The last one fails, the program still works while it shouldn't:

```
sudo capsh --user=jdoe --keep=1 --caps="all=eip" --addamb="all" --delamb="cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search" -- -c ./binary
```

Is there some difference between filesystem and process capabilities that I fail to notice?
How do I write the third test properly?

Comment: When you run `capsh`, what are the file capabilities on `./binary`? File capabilities are specific to the file and always override ambient capabilities. Try running `sudo setcap -r ./binary` before you try the `capsh` command.

Comment: @AndrewGMorgan, There are no file capabilities when I run `capsh` because I already do what you suggest. Clarifying the question, thanks.

Comment: FWIW I think you mean "three" when you say "tree". I think there must be some detail of your program (`binary`) that isn't working the way you think. I'll provide an answer which shows things working as you imagine they should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think the answer to your question lies in what your program is doing. (In general, it always good to provide some simplified source code with your question to reproduce what you are seeing.)

I've quickly coded something up (in Go, because its slightly less code to generate debug output than C and [`libcap`](https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/), and it provides a working example of the [`cap`](https://pkg.go.dev/kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/security/libcap/cap) go package).

This is `binary.go`:

```go
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/security/libcap/cap"
)

func confirm(c *cap.Set, val cap.Value) int {
    on, err := c.GetFlag(cap.Effective, val)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to confirm %q in effective set: %v", val, err)
    }
    log.Printf("%q in effective set of %q is: %v", val, c, on)
    if on {
        return 0
    }
    return 1
}

func fail() {
    log.Print("FAILURE")
    os.Exit(1)
}

func main() {
    c := cap.GetProc()
    if confirm(c, cap.SYS_ADMIN) != 0 {
        fail()
    }
    if confirm(c, cap.DAC_OVERRIDE)+confirm(c, cap.DAC_READ_SEARCH) > 1 {
        fail()
    }
    log.Print("SUCCESS")
}
```

Compile it as follows:

```
$ go mod init binary
$ go mod tidy
$ go build binary.go
$ ./binary 
2022/09/10 16:45:56 "cap_sys_admin" in effective set of "=" is: false
2022/09/10 16:45:56 FAILURE
$ echo $?
1
```

This program, `binary`, has all of the properties that you describe and works the way you expect it to. Where things differ between the file capability version and the *Ambient* inheritance version (the one that uses `capsh`) is there are *Inheritable* process capabilities present:

```go
$ sudo setcap 'all=ep cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search-ep' ./binary
$ ./binary 
2022/09/10 16:50:37 "cap_sys_admin" in effective set of "=ep cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search-ep" is: true
2022/09/10 16:50:37 "cap_dac_override" in effective set of "=ep cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search-ep" is: false
2022/09/10 16:50:37 "cap_dac_read_search" in effective set of "=ep cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search-ep" is: false
2022/09/10 16:50:37 FAILURE
$ sudo setcap -r binary
$ sudo capsh --user=$(whoami) --keep=1 --caps="all=eip" --addamb="all" --delamb="cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search" -- -c ./binary
2022/09/10 16:52:21 "cap_sys_admin" in effective set of "=eip cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search-ep" is: true
2022/09/10 16:52:21 "cap_dac_override" in effective set of "=eip cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search-ep" is: false
2022/09/10 16:52:21 "cap_dac_read_search" in effective set of "=eip cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search-ep" is: false
2022/09/10 16:52:21 FAILURE
```

That is, you see `"=ep"` in the file capability version and `"=eip"` in the *Ambient* one. The `".i."` part is not a capability that is useful to the program directly, it only comes into play when a program is executed.

I think your code might be checking for *Inheritable* process capabilities. Again, these are *not* privilege on their own. They only represent privilege when they are combined with file *Inheritable* capabilities, or *Ambient* capabilities. I've done a full write up of how capability inheritance works on the [`libcap` distribution website](https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/inheriting-privilege). If all this stuff is still confusing, the examples there might be helpful.